# Tool to easily manage multiple Tomcat instances and their ports

Tags: java, web-server

So far I have been using Eclipse with its tomcat server integration. It creates multiple directories(each for every application group deployed). Switched back to Intellij Community which does not support any of this.

Is there some tool which I can use to manage multiple tomcat instance. I know I can copy the tomcat, but then I will need to care about ports manually. There is Codehause Cargo project, but I don't see how to use it without pollute my maven files. Furthermore Cargo daemon does not allow for easy port management.

Any other solution?

Comment: Does it have to run within IntelliJ? Or standalone?

Comment: Does not matter, maybe standalone solution little bit more preferred. Just tried out SmartTomcat plugin for IntelliJ, but was unable to make it work.